# Some People just ask questions, Not giving answers at all

Tags: discussion

I have found couple of people who just asking question , But never give any answer or never try to give answer We need to take some action against them.
Because they are taking benefit from community but not giving anything to community . Please see couple of user as they are asking questions only are listed below.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/22561/sachin-s

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/39050/jeeva-rathinam

Comment: Really good question, I completely agree on your point, but what i guess is members who created account before 1.5 years may not have complete 1.5 yrs exp on magento. 
they might worked on other platformas also like wordpress, drupal, joomla etc.... but i appreciate your concern for the community & its great that you answered more questions than asking.

Comment: I always Believe in that If you have knowledge then check your knowledge and share your knowledge with others. And also I am expecting with others that if you are a member of this community then share your knowledge with others

Comment: What you said is `Golden words - sharing` , your point not only applicable for community also for all things in world.
if all rich peploes share their money with poor, than it will be awesome, no persons in the world will die by hungry....

Comment: @BabyinMagento pretty ironical coming from someone that has almost 500 questions (ratio of ~5:1 with answers) and kept spamming the community for a while don't you think?

Comment: Here we are talking about the people who dont answer at all If you are giving less answer that is okay But you are ignoring people while you have answer and also you use community for your own selfishly then its wrong

Comment: Have some mercy, this poor guy is desparately trying to export products for several weeks now and is not able to communicate his problems clearly. Questions are downvoted and closed quickly, most probably eventually deleted, and because they are of very low quality, nobody can help anyways. This is already handled well, I'd say.

Comment: Also read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem

Comment: @JulienLachal and #BabyinMagetno Still a Better Love Story than Twilight

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara He is quite new user leave him now

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara for new user we can put exception that they are new in magento and while they are learning they may be not understand something

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/783/marty-wallace  this also

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about taking actions to help them instead of against them?
If the questions are high quality questions, then they help the community.
If not, just downvote them, or vote to close them.
You cannot force the people to answer if they don't know how to answer or if they don't want to answer.
Just for the record jeeva-rathinam already has a temporary ban for violating the terms of this website.
That's the most I'm willing to do.
I will not delete an account just because they don't have any answers.
I don't think it's healthy to open this pandora's box.
If I do this, people might start arguing that 10 answers in 11 months is not that much either.
I don't want to go that way.

Comment: But if person has 1.5 years of exp. then they have some knowledge and if they are asking good questions then they also have very good answers but they are not sharing their knowledge with community  , that is not good

Comment: I undersrstand you, but you cannot force people to help if they don't want to. In every community there will be lurkers. It's how it works. You can track them down and break their hands or something. (just for the record, I was trying to be sarcastic. I don't encourage violence - in this case.)

Comment: Ok Thank you for your answers and support for this community.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what Marius said and if you don't feel like closing or downvoting, **you have the right to ignore the questions asked by the people you mentioned** if you are not fine with the way they behave.